# DOS Batch: extract from string

Tags: xml, batch-file, text-extraction

I need to extract strings included between XML tags. Why is the code below not working ? The Shell window opens and closes down immediatly, despite the 'pause' instruction.

```
@echo off
set var="<AAA>E086263-T1999</AAA>"

for f/ "delims=>< tokens=2" %%a in (%var%) do echo %%a
pause
```

Many thanks for help !

Comment: Have you tried `for /f`?

Comment: Yes, that's what I've put in my example...

Comment: No, you have used `for f/`

Comment: Yep, perfect ! Sorry I missed it...